# AWS EC2 > IGW Outbound Traffic Filtering by Domain or URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have EC2 Instance with **Windows Server**, i'm using it **only with RDP**. Can I somehow block outbound traffic **from browser to specific domain** (eg. abc.example.com) or URL? I'd rather do it in the AWS Dashboard so that RDP users do not have access to whitelist this domain/URL.

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a native AWS solution for this, of course you could allow only specific IP addresses. The problem with this is for domains these may change, when you look at Cloud you can see that many services (such as load balancers and CDNs) will be changing their IP address.

The ideal solutions is that you would deploy a software (running on EC2) that is able to filter outbound traffic based on domain name. There are solutions on the AWS Marketplace, as well as filtering using a dumb proxy.

The network setup would involve you creating a number of subnets containing the EC2 instances. These would have a route table forwarding all traffic (0.0.0.0/0) to a NAT.

Then for all applications that need to have their outbound traffic filtered they would update their route table to route all traffic (0.0.0.0/0) to the ENI of one of the filtering hosts (ideally in the same AZ).

More information: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-an-outbound-vpc-proxy-with-domain-whitelisting-and-content-filtering/

Answer (score 1):

You can configure [Access Control Lists](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html) (ACL) and [Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html) to filter outbound traffic. However, both of those tools only allow filtering based on IP address, not domain.

If you are confident that the IP addresses won't change, then you can configure these services. If you aren't interested in maintaining a blacklist, then you might need to check on some OS-level limits.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and easiest way is to implement an Aviatrix FQDN egress filter. It just serves the purpose from a centralized user interface to whitelist/blacklist the URLs in every VPC.

Next Generation Firewall (NGFW) implementation, just to achieve URL / FQDN filtering is an overkill, esp. from the cost point of view whereas proxy implementation has its complexity and doesn't provide centralized control, every VPC has to be managed separately.

The easiest way is to get an Aviatrix launch partner like SDxWORx, enable it with discounted PAYG pricing.

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-laruhupdkcpuy/